# How to add cvblob_DIR for find_package?

Tags: ros, opencv, catkin, linking, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use Groovy, but i get blocked every time:
I want to use **cvBlob** with **opencv** in ROS. I installed both, my test program works in opencv. I think there shouldn't be any problem with the installation of this libs. My `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to `/opt/ros/groovy/lib`, so i also copied there the **libcvblob.so**.
When I try to implement in groovy the same applicationo I get a nasty error after linking:

```
Linking CXX executable /home/elod/myWS/devel/lib/bagDetect/bagDetect
CMakeFiles/bagDetect.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `corridorProces(cv::Mat&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to `cvLabel'
main.cpp:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `cvRenderBlobs'
main.cpp:(.text+0x328): undefined reference to `cvLabel'
main.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `cvRenderBlobs'
CMakeFiles/bagDetect.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `imageCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xca2): undefined reference to `image_transport::Publisher::publish(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) const'
CMakeFiles/bagDetect.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10c8): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::ImageTransport(ros::NodeHandle const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x13ca): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::advertise(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1525): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::~ImageTransport()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1794): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::~ImageTransport()'
CMakeFiles/bagDetect.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribe(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), image_transport::TransportHints const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN15image_transport14ImageTransport9subscribeERKSsjPFvRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEEERKNS_14TransportHintsE[image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribe(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), image_transport::TransportHints const&)]+0x5d): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribe(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&, boost::shared_ptr<void> const&, image_transport::TransportHints const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/elod/myWS/devel/lib/bagDetect/bagDetect] Error 1
```

My **package.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>bagDetect</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The bagDetect package</description>
  <maintainer email="elod@todo.todo">elod</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>          
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>OpenCV</build_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>OpenCV</run_depend>
</package>
```

My **CMakeList.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bagDetect)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cv_bridge roscpp rospy std_msgs)
catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include 
#  LIBRARIES bagDetect
  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge roscpp
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
/home/elod/opencv/cmake/
)

add_executable(bagDetect src/main.cpp)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(bagDetect ${OpenCV_LIBS})

include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/FindPkgConfig.cmake)
pkg_check_modules(CVBLOB REQUIRED cvBlob)
include_directories(${CVBLOB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${CVBLOB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(bagDetect ${CVBLOB_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(bagDetect ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

From **mian.cpp** the fnc with **cvblob** stuff:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
// for img processing 
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
// for blob detect
#include "cvblob.h"
#include <map>
.
...
Mat& corridorProces(Mat& resultImg)
{
    
    IplImage src= resultImg.clone();
        IplImage *labelImg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src_g), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);

    cvb::CvBlobs blobs;
    unsigned int result=cvb::cvLabel(src_g, labelImg, blobs);   
    cvRenderBlobs(labelImg, blobs, &src, &src);
...
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56356/how-to-add-cvblob_dir-for-find_package?/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out that CMakeList.txt should be like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bagDetect)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED sensor_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge roscpp std_msgs image_transport)
catkin_package()
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(bagD src/main.cpp)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(bagD ${OpenCV_LIBS})
find_package(cvBlob REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(bagD ${cvBlob_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(bagD   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0